# Angular validation in form field directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

the validation isn't working in my formRow directive. I put a ng-form with the field name in the directive, but the [[ field ]].$invalid for example will not triggered. Does anybody know why?

Directive:

```
<li class="form__row" ng-form="[[ field ]]">
<div class="label">
    <label ng-class="{ 'required' : required == 'true' }" for="frm-[[ field ]]">[[ label ]]</label>
</div>
<div class="field" ng-switch="required" ng-class="{ 'field--invalid' : [[ field ]].$touched && [[ field ]].$invalid, 'field--valid': [[ field ]].$touched && [[ field ]].$valid }">
    <input ng-switch-when="true" type="[[ type ]]" name="[[ field ]]" id="frm-[[ field ]]" ng-model="record[ field ]" required>
    <input ng-switch-default type="[[ type ]]" name="[[ field ]]" id="frm-[[ field ]]" ng-model="record[ field ]" >
</div>
```

Directive.js

```
.directive('formRow', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: FW.Config.submap + 'angular/_directives/formRow.html',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        record: '=',
        type: '@',
        field: '@',
        label: '@',
        required: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {
        // Wordt gezet bij form submit
        $scope.$on('record:invalid', function() {
            $scope[$scope.field].$setTouched;
        });
    }
}
})
```

Call from template:

```
<form name="formData" ng-submit="submit($event)" class="form--wide frm-login" novalidate>
    <ul>
        <form-row record="inloggen" field="emailadres" label="E-mailadres" type="email" required="true"></form-row>
        <form-row record="inloggen" field="wachtwoord" label="Wachtwoord" type="password" required="true"></form-row>
    </ul>
```

By the way: I use square brackets as $interpolateProvider symbols, because of the use of twig also in my templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is very good idea to create such directive, but the main problem and what makes it pretty awkward is that you are using nested form directive `ngForm` with the same name as corresponding element. It adds up to the scope level.

You can make `ngClass` work properly with this expression (I warned this looks weird :) :

```
ng-class="{ 'field--invalid' : this[field][field].$touched && this[field][field].$invalid, 'field--valid': this[field][field].$touched && this[field][field].$valid }"
```

First of all note, that you don't use interpolation tags inside of expressions, so you don't need `[[ ]]` inside `ngClass`. Then in order to resolve dynamic object property by variable name you would use bracket notation, hence

```
this[field][field]
```

Here you have:

- `this` points to current scope object
- `this[field]` points to the `ngForm` object which has the same name as defined in `field` for input element and parent `ngForm`
- `this[field][field]` point to individual input element within form accessed by `this[field]`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/zarnKqPnYw4BNQQKVy9t?p=info